# waiting in the main code while asynchronous call for get method executes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, get

```
void main() {
    OpenWeatherApiClient.getCurrentLocationWeatherAsync(55.513434, -37.53434, (x) => {
        Console.WriteLine(x.coord.lat);
        Console.ReadLine();
    });
}

Console.WriteLine("this should happen before");
/// I want to hold the the function here till the call back returns and executes the above logic

/// the asynchronous function
public static void getCurrentLocationWeatherAsync(double latitude, double longitude, Action<WeatherData> callback) {
    //weather from one station
    string weatherSearch = "weather?lat={0}&lon={1}";

    var url = string.Concat(baseUrl, weatherSearch);
    //Customize the URL according to the geo location
    url = string.Format(url, latitude, longitude);
    //Syncronous consumption
    var asynClient = new WebClient();
    //add Appid for verification
    asynClient.Headers.Add(APPIDName, APPID);

    asynClient.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) => {
        if (callback != null) {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(WeatherData));
            callback(ser.ReadObject(a.Result) as WeatherData);
        }
    };
    asynClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
}
```

I have maid this asynchronous get method, after parsing the request into data contract. While i want to hold the main method till the getcall and associate code in the delegate are completely executed.
In future what i want is to concurrently call more than get methods and hold them till all of them execute.
After which i would proceed in the main since the data from each get call is dependent

Comment: Why do you run asynchronous code when you actually want to hold the executing thread?

Comment: Sorry i did not get the point. But I am using the async service calls  because i have to call multiple service methods  and do not want to wait for response of the first call and then move on two the second

Comment: You want to call the `getCurrentLocationWeatherAsync` method multiple times and then wait until all of them finished or am I understanding your question wrong?

Comment: Yes, the idea is same but I want to call two other methods getCityWeatherDatAsync and getFivehourlyDataAsync. And wait in the main code while all of these methods return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly:

```
private static readonly List<Task> weatherTasks = new List<Task>(); 

public static void GetCurrentLocationWeatherAsync(double latitude, double longitude, Action<WeatherData> callback)
{
    // ...
    weatherTasks.Add(asynClient.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(url)));
}

public static void WaitForAllWeatherCalls()
{
    Task.WaitAll(weatherTasks.ToArray());
    weatherTasks.Clear();
}
```

Create a list of tasks then change the `OpenReadAsync` to `OpenReadTaskAsync` and put the Task into the list. The method `WaitForAllWeatherCalls` is then just waiting for all currently running tasks and is then clearing the tasks (be aware that the code is not thread safe).

Why this code is not thread-safe:
Lets say we have a Thread A and a Thread B. A calls the `GetCurrentLocationWeatherAsync` multiple times then wants to wait for these calls. So thread A calls `WaitForAllWeatherCalls` and is now waiting. While thread A is waiting thread B also wants to get some weather data. Thread B calls `GetCurrentLocationWeatherAsync` multiple times. The Task list now contains some tasks of thread A and some of thread B. The problem comes up when the waiting of thread a is over, because the task list will be cleared. When thread B wants to wait on all his data there will not be any tasks in the list and thread B won't even pause once.

A better version:

```
class WeatherGatherer
{
    private readonly List<Task> weatherTasks = new List<Task>();

    public void GetCurrentLocationWeatherAsync(double latitude, double longitude, Action<WeatherData> callback)
    {
        // ...
        weatherTasks.Add(asynClient.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(url)));
    }

    public void WaitForAllWeatherCalls()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(weatherTasks.ToArray());
        weatherTasks.Clear();
    }
}
```

The hole thing is now in a class instead of being static. The class itself is still not thread-safe but if you always creating one instance for one group of 'weather-data gathering' you won't have a problem.

Remember that thread-safety is only a problem when you have more than one thread.

Comment: Thank you this has started to work. I am still knew to this so can you explain    what do you mean by code is not thread safe and how can i make it more safer

Comment: I added an explanation but remember that if you are not using more than one thread you can simply use the upper version.

Answer (score 0):

Any alternatives to do the same above logic would also be really great

I was previously doing it this way but could not continue because the event would not return deserialized objec

```
//public static async Task<WeatherData> getCurrentLocationWeatherAsync(double latitude, double longitude)
    //{
    //    //weather from one station
    //    string weatherSearch = "weather?lat={0}&lon={1}";

    //    var url = string.Concat(baseUrl, weatherSearch);
    //    //Customize the URL according to the geo location
    //    url = string.Format(url,latitude, longitude);
    //    //Syncronous consumption
    //     var asynClient = new WebClient();
    //    //add Appid for verification
    //    asynClient.Headers.Add(APPIDName,APPID);
    //    asynClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(asyncClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    //    // API call
    //     var response = await asynClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    //    //content=content.Replace("3h", "precipitation__3h");
    //    //create Json Serializer and parse the response


    //}

    //static void asyncClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    // Create the Json serializer and parse the response
    //    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(WeatherData));
    //    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result)))
    //    {
    //        // deserialize the JSON object using the WeatherData type.
    //        var weatherData = (WeatherData)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

    //        // return weatherData;
    //    }
//}
```